# webpack-dev-server error after migrating to Angular 13

Tags: angular, webpack, browser

After my migration from angular 12 to angular 13, i am getting the following error in the console: [image: webpack-dev-server error, index.js line 558. On new line: Event object, isTrusted true, type 'error', target WebSocket, currentTarget WebSocket, eventPhase 2, ellipsis]

Also if i change something in my code the browser does not reload automatically.

Note: I have no extra configuration for webpack.

Here are my package-versions of my `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.1.1",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^7.0.4",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract-marker": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/hashids": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.12",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.31.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.31.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "36.0.8",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "hashids": "^2.2.8",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "postcss": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.2"
  }
```

Comment: If you clean the project directory (remove node_modules and build artifacts), reinstall dependencies and start, what happens?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I am having the same issue. I am running angular in a docker container.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by using `--public-host` while serving the app.

E.g. if your app is served on port 4200 add `--public-host localhost:4200` (more info here https://angular.io/cli/serve)

Or set it in the `angular.json` file like this:

```
"serve": {
  [...],
  "options": {
      [...],
      "publicHost": "localhost:4200"
},
```

As far as I can tell, the reason for this error was that we are using a proxy with which all requests were proxied and for whatever reason the websocket was not able to connect this way.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error (no live reload, websocket connection failed to localhost:9000) too when upgrading from Angular 12 to Angular 13. For my case we are using @angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server with a proxy configuration. Apparently, the websocket just does not listen to the correct port when `ng serve`, it only works when we `ng build`.
We are proxying 4200 to port 9000 but the live reloading event only works on the default port 4200, so we have to explicitly tell the webpack/websocket to listen to the correct port.

In order to get it working properly when `ng serve` Just make sure to add this flag to your `ng serve` command where `<PORT>` is the actual prot you are serving to (not the proxied one):

```
ng serve --public-host localhost:<PORT>
```

For my case it was `ng serve --public-host localhost:4200`. The cause is probably from the new webpack version I assume, because this error only shows when we upgrade to the latest version of @angular/cli & @angular-builders/custom-webpack, it does not appear in ~12 version, only ~13 versions.

Here is my `angular.json:projects:test-app:architect:serve` json obj (note the proxy custom webpack and proxy config)

```json
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "test-app:build",
    "proxyConfig": "./webpack/proxy.conf.js"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "test-app:build:production"
    },
    "development": {
      "browserTarget": "test-app:build:development"
    }
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "development"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately @ianpea this did not work for me. Confused as to why...